# Control flow with match statement in OCaml: unexpected early return

Tags: ocaml

I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding in how expressions are defined as valid targets for patterns in OCaml `match` statements. In this simple example, I cannot understand the control flow behavior of the program.

```
open Printf

let () =
  let a = None in
  match a with
  | Some s -> printf "%s\n" s
  | None -> printf "None.\n";
  printf "Here.\n";
  let b = Some "string" in
  match b with
  | Some s -> printf "%s.\n" s
  | None -> printf "None.\n";
  printf "There.\n"
```

With my current understanding of control flow I'd expect the output to be:

```
None.
Here.
string.
There.
```

But instead the entry point function returns early before reaching `printf "There.\n"`. I notice this only happens when the a pattern other than the last pattern matches. So far I've tried the approaches I've seen elsewhere for grouping multiple expression in this context like `begin` and `end` to no avail. Is there a better way to group a sequence statements in `match` expressions, or am I just abusing the construct?

Comment: For clarity, wrap the whole `match … with …` statement in parenthesis. (Or `begin` and `end`, if you prefer those)

Comment: Alternatively, try to indent the `match` cases further

Comment: Please install auto indentation tool for your editor like `ocp-indent`.  It helps you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts of the `match` statement after `->` can contain any number of semicolon-separated statements. So your code should be indented like this:

```
let () =
  let a = None in
  match a with
  | Some s -> printf "%s\n" s
  | None -> printf "None.\n";
            printf "Here.\n";
            let b = Some "string" in
            match b with
            | Some s -> printf "%s.\n" s
            | None -> printf "None.\n";
                      printf "There.\n"
```

The expected output is:

```
None.
Here.
string.
```

**Update**

You can parenthesize (or use `begin/end` which is completely equivalent in OCaml) to get the sequencing that corresponds to your indentation:

```
let () =
  let a = None in
  (match a with
  | Some s -> printf "%s\n" s
  | None -> printf "None.\n"
  );
  printf "Here.\n";
  let b = Some "string" in   
  (match b with
  | Some s -> printf "%s.\n" s
  | None -> printf "None.\n"
  );
  printf "There.\n"
```

Side comment: here's an example of `begin/end`:

```
# begin 3 + 5 end * 7;;
- : int = 56
```

It's really true, parentheses and `begin/end` are equivalent in OCaml.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I wanted to close out the first match statement so that I would be guaranteed to execute statements following it, is there syntax to do that? To make a series of match statements more or less straight line code?

Comment: You can parenthesize, as @bergi points out. I'll add a little bit to my answer.